React-Query Suspense Mode Not Showing Loading State
I'm working on a React project where I'm trying to use the @tanstack/react-query library with Suspense to handle the loading state. However, the loading fallback is not showing up while fetching the images (screenshot attached below).
Here is a simplified version of my app:
App Component:
import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import ImageList from "./components/suspense/ImageList";

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <ImageList />
    </QueryClientProvider>
  );
};

export default App;

Fetch Function and Custom Hook:
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

export interface PicsumImage {
  id: string;
  author: string;
  download_url: string;
}

const fetchPicsumImages = async (): Promise<PicsumImage[]> => {
  const response = await fetch("https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=1&limit=5");
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Network response was not ok");
  }
  return response.json();
};

const usePicsumImages = () => {
  return useQuery<PicsumImage[]>({
    queryKey: ["picsumImages"],
    queryFn: fetchPicsumImages,
  });
};

export default usePicsumImages;

ImageList Component:
import usePicsumImages from "./usePicsumImages";

const ImageList = () => {
  const { data } = usePicsumImages();

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 gap-4">
      {data?.map((image) => (
        <div key={image.id} className="rounded shadow-md overflow-hidden">
          <img
            src={image.download_url}
            alt={image.author}
            className="w-full h-48 object-cover"
          />
          <p className="p-2 text-center text-sm font-medium">
            Photo by: {image.author}
          </p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageList;

import { Suspense } from "react";
import ImageList from "./ImageList";

const ImageContainer = () => {
  return (
    <div className="p-6 font-sans">
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold text-center mb-6">Image Gallery</h1>
      <Suspense
        fallback={
          <div className="text-center text-lg text-black">
            Loading images...
          </div>
        }
      >
      <ImageList />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageContainer;

My Environment:

React: 18.3.1
@tanstack/react-query: 5.62.7

Screenshot:


What could be causing the issue with Suspense fallback? How can I fix this to properly show the loading state when fetching the images?

React's Suspense is working as designed here.  The issue is that React is rendering your tree, waiting until the response from usePicsumImages is available and then rendering a bunch of images.  It has no idea that you want to wait for the images to load too, nor does it have any insight into the loading state of the images in order to wait for them.
Fortunately, that's easy to fix:
import { useEffect, useState, ImgHTMLAttributes } from React;

function SuspendingImage(props: ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>): JSX.Element {
  const [state, setState] = useState(Promise.withResolvers);

  // Here we pre-load the image, also wiring up
  // our promise to resolve or reject once
  // the image has loaded or failed.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!state) return;
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => { state.resolve(); setState(null); };
    img.onerror = (e) => { state.reject(e); setState(null); };
    img.src = props.src;
    return () => { img.onload = img.onerror = null; };
  }, [state]);

  // The integration with Suspense is here
  // As long as we haven't finished loading
  // we'll signal to React that we're still waiting
  if (state) throw state.promise;

  // We'll only get here once the image load in useEffect
  // has completed and our `setState(null)` calls have run.
  return <img {...props} />;
}

export default SuspendingImage;

Then you just replace <img src= with <SuspendingImage src= and things should just-work.
